# knockout binding object, field value will not update after input value

Tags: knockout.js

why binding on object ,the object value will not update.
but the valueitem will change after keyup.

```js
function Model() {
        this.Id = "",
        this.Name = "aa"
        
    };
var vm = {
   item: ko.observable(new Model()),
   valueitem:ko.observable('bbbbb')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: item">
<input id='test' data-bind="value: Name"></input>
<p>You have input name : <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></p>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<input id='test' data-bind="value: valueitem"></input>
<p>You have input value: <span data-bind="text: valueitem"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `maaaagik` said, you have to make the Id and Name properties as ko.observable inorder to observe the changes in name and id.

```
function Model() {
        this.Id = ko.observable(""),
        this.Name = ko.observable("aa")

    };
var vm = {
   item: ko.observable(new Model()),
   valueitem:ko.observable('bbbbb')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: thanks, it's work,but this will arise another question, the object property need convert to function.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that simply `Name` is not an observable. Try it like this:

```
var model = {
    Id: ko.observable(""),
    Name: ko.observable("aa")
}
var vm = {
   item: ko.observable(model),
   valueitem:ko.observable('bbbbb'),   
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Cheers